# Live Scale in MAGELLAN 8500XT

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner, pos

We are facing a time delay issue in live scaling. we have used Microsoft Point Of Service SDK using ScaleLiveWeight function in window base application(C#) but it's Scaling is taking 2 seconds to scale the product but we want to make it a little faster than now,

Kindly help us to find any solutions for LiveWeight scaling faster.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you can [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing the code that performs badly.  Also, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a more appropriate forum for your question, they accept questions about improving the performance of code that already works correctly, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also make sure to provide info from device's datasheet to show what is expected time for the operation...

Comment: There seems to be no function to adjust the delay with device settings or commands. [Datalogic Magellan 8500Xt Product Reference Guide](https://cdn.datalogic.com/upload/res/manuals/adc/820032814.pdf), [jdpurdyvi/Magellan 8500](https://gist.github.com/jdpurdyvi/853672), [MettlerToledo Diva Service Manual PSC 8500 Magellan Scanner](https://www.mt.com/dam/RET_DOCS/Diva_Checkout_DatalogicMagellan8500_UserGuide.pdf), [Datalogic OPOS Service Objects](https://postorg.com.ua/published/file/Datalogic/820025614_revK.pdf)